# Finding a subsequence (of a very long sequence) which does not sum to an even number

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, random

[*Edited.* I've revised to problem to focus on the special case of the integers modulo 2.]

You are given a function *f* from binary strings **x** ∈ {0,1}<sup>*n*</sup> to the integers, or (without loss of generality) just to {0,1}.
You are promised only that *f* is not entirely even numbers.

**Question.** With only poly(*n*) random bits, how do you describe a subset *S* ⊂ {0,1}<sup>*n*</sup> so that, with probability at least 1/poly(*n*), the sum (modulo *p*) of *f*(**x**)  over all **x** ∈ *S* is odd?

I'm interested in efficient algorithms; for instance, searching for a single **x** ∈ {0,1}<sup>*n*</sup> for which *f*(**x**) is odd, by evaluating most of the values of **x**, is not allowed (as this takes exponential time in the worst case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notwithstanding my naive skepticism expressed in my comment, it turns out that this is possible: the proof of the [Valiant-Vazirani theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valiant%E2%80%93Vazirani_theorem) gives such an $S$.

- As a preliminary step, guess the size of $\{ x \colon f(x) \text{ is odd} \}$ up to a factor of 2: i.e., guess an $r$ such that the size of that set is in the window $[2^{r-1}, 2^r)$. This guess is correct with probability $1/(n+1)$.
- Pick $S$ to be a random subcube of codimension around $r$. (The codimension should be $r \pm$ an absolute constant. I do not know the details off the top of my head; I will update my answer later to make this precise). Then conditioned on our first guess being right, with a constant probability, it can be shown that there is exactly one $x \in S$ such that $f(x)$ is odd.

Thus $\sum \limits_{x \in S} f(x)$ is odd with probability $\Omega (\frac{1}{n})$. Done! (The description of $S$ takes $O(n)$ random bits.)

Comment: In retrospect, this cuts right to the heart of the problem: the sum of the integer sequence is effectively #SAT in disguise, and I'm effectively asking how to reduce the number of satisfying solutions to an odd number, e.g. a unique satisfying solution. The same principle applies for any finite field. I'll look over your answer after I've rested, and likely accept it then. :-)